# Solution set to cross product

Tags: vector-spaces, cross-product

If $\vec a,\vec b \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with $|\vec a|\ne0$ show that the equation $\vec a \times \vec u =\vec b$ has a solution if and only if $a \cdot b = 0$ and find all the solutions in this case.

The answer for the general solution to **u** is,

$-\dfrac{\vec a \times \vec b}{\lvert \vec a \rvert^2} + t \vec a $, where $t$ is a real parameter.

The first part is trivial, but I have no idea how to find the solution set.
Could anybody shed any light on this matter? I would be very grateful.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: Do you know the fact that $(\vec a\times \vec b)$ is $\perp$ to $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  $(\vec a\times \vec b)$ is $\perp$ to $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ both.So, you get $\vec a \cdot \vec b=0$
and $$\vec a\times \vec a=0$$ 
So, general solution for $\vec u=t\vec a+ \vec c$ . where $\vec a , \vec c $ are linearly independent (ie. $\vec a\cdot \vec c=0$) and  $\vec a\times \vec c=\vec b$.

Now you can proceed. `:)` You have to find $\vec c$ satisfying it.

> HINT: You need to use vector triple product. Pre-cross multiply with $\vec a$ on both sides of $\vec a\times \vec c=\vec b$.
>
> ---
>
> $\vec x\times (\vec y \times \vec z)=(\vec x \cdot \vec z) \vec y - (\vec x \cdot \vec y)\vec z$

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! :) Could you explain exactly what spurred you to take the steps that you did in order to arrive at the solution?